# Getting "Updates can only be scheduled from GUI thread.." when setting mainWindow visibile=false

Tags: qt, qml, warnings, visibility

In QML code we have a button handler that sets the top level window 'visible' property to false. When this code executes we see approximately 3160 lines of 
 
"Updates can only be scheduled from GUI thread or from QQuickItem::updatePaintNode()" on the console output.
Note: 
The main window does go invisible after all these warning messages finish being output.
We routinely set other components visible properties to true/false with no warning message apparent.
Setting the visible property back to true (after setting it to false) does not display a warning message.

QML:

```
Window{
    id:mainWindow
    visible:true
    ...
    ...
}

Rectangle{
    color:"black"
    ...
    MouseArea{
        onClicked: mainWindow.visible=false;    
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are wanting to execute some task that updates the GUI view directly from a different thread to the GUI. Does the code that you are showing think you reproduce the error?

Comment: In your code, the *button* is no child to the toplevel window?

Comment: @derM - my apologies the button is actually a child of the window. I should have been more more precise in writing out the code sample.